# boostrap collapse is not working in my react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

bootstrap collapse  is not working in my react app .

i want the collapse functionality in my app
it is not working in my reactapp.

i think bootstrap classes are working but bootstrap onclick is not working

codesandbox code
[codesandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-feather-pifzxs)

bootstrap code
[bootstrap link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#example) 
solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to insall three dependencies in your app

1. bootstrap
2. jquery
3. @popperjs/core

you have to keep all the script tags in the index.html page

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script
```